# Conditions if not null in where in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I need to get all values from the table where:

- if datetime column 'start' is not null and less or equal than now. If it is null I need to ignore start verification.
- if datetime column 'stop' is not null and more or equal than now. If it is null I need to ignore stop verification

So I created this request

```
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME;
SET @currDate = GETDATE();

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE   
     -- here I have some other conditions
    AND @currDate >=  (CASE WHEN table.validityStart IS NOT NULL THEN table.validityStart ELSE @currDate END)
    AND @currDate <=  (CASE WHEN table.validityStop IS NOT NULL THEN table.validityStop ELSE @currDate END)
```

So if start or stop is null I compare current datetime with itself. I do not think that it is best way of create this request.

So is there any possibility to avoid verification in 'where' section if value is null but not compare it with itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can write the condition in the following way:

```
AND (table.validityStart IS NULL OR table.validityStart<=@currDate) 
AND (table.validityStop IS NULL OR table.validityStop >=@currDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't SQL Server support coalesce? (i.e. pick first non-null value.)

```
AND @currDate >=  coalesce(table.validityStart, @currDate)
AND @currDate <=  coalesce(table.validityStop, @currDate)
```

Comment: Yee, it's possible solution, but it is not SARG here.